# Java Regex to extract an id string, based on recurring sub-string of each id

Tags: java, regex

I am reading in a log file and extracting certain data contained with in the file. I am able to extract the time for each line of the log file.

Now I want to extract the id `"ieatrcxb4498-1"`. All of the id's start with the sub string `ieatrcxb`  which I have tried to query and return the full string based on it.

I have tried many different suggestions from other posts. But I have been unsuccessful, with the following patterns:

```
(?i)\\b("ieatrcxb"(?:.+?)?)\\b
(?i)\\b\\w*"ieatrcxb"\\w*\\b"
^.*ieatrcxb.*$
```

I have also tried to extract the full id based, on the String starting with `i` and finishing in `1`. As they all do.

**Line of the log file**

```
150: 2017-06-14 18:02:21 INFO  monitorinfo           :     Info: Lock VCS on node "ieatrcxb4498-1"
```

**Code**

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader(new File("lock-unlock.txt")));
    //Record currentRecord = null;
    ArrayList<Record> list = new ArrayList<>();

    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = s.nextLine();

        Record newRec = new Record();
        // newRec.time =
        newRec.time = regexChecker("([0-1]?\\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\\d):([0-5]?\\d)", line);

        newRec.ID = regexChecker("^.*ieatrcxb.*$", line);

        list.add(newRec);

    }


public static String regexChecker(String regEx, String str2Check) {

    Pattern checkRegex = Pattern.compile(regEx);
    Matcher regexMatcher = checkRegex.matcher(str2Check);
    String regMat = "";
    while(regexMatcher.find()){
        if(regexMatcher.group().length() !=0)
            regMat = regexMatcher.group();
        }
        //System.out.println("Inside the "+ regexMatcher.group().trim());
    }

     return regMat;
}
```

I need a simple pattern which will do this for me.

Comment: "a log file and extracting certain data contained with in the file" - What kind of data, what kind of log file? Post an example.

Comment: @user3734782150: 2017-06-14 18:02:21 INFO monitorinfo : Info: Lock VCS on node "ieatrcxb4498-1" this is a sample of the data from the log file.

Comment: So you want to extract whole line containing the id ?

Comment: @user3734782 no just the id it's self. Each line of the file has an id and want to take the id from each one. I have done it with the time, as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the ID always have the format "`ieatrcxb` followed by 4 digits, followed by `-`, followed by 1 digit"?

If that's the case, you can do:

```
regexChecker("ieatrcxb\\d{4}-\\d", line);
```

Note the `{4}` quantifier, which matches exactly 4 digits (`\\d`). If the last digit is always `1`, you could also use `"ieatrcxb\\d{4}-1"`.

If the number of digits vary, you can use `"ieatrcxb\\d+-\\d+"`, where `+` means "1 or more".

You can also use the `{}` quantifier with the mininum and maximum number of occurences. Example: `"ieatrcxb\\d{4,6}-\\d"` - `{4,6}` means "minimum of 4 and maximum of 6 occurrences" (**that's just an example, I don't know if that's your case**). This is useful if you know exactly how many digits the ID can have.

All of the above work for your case, returning `ieatrcxb4498-1`. Which one to use will depend on how your input varies.

---

If you want just the numbers without the `ieatrcxb` part (`4498-1`), you can use a [lookbehind regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
regexChecker("(?<=ieatrcxb)\\d{4,6}-\\d", line);
```

This makes `ieatrcxb` to not be part of the match, thus returning just `4498-1`.

If you also don't want the `-1` and just `4498`, you can combine this with a lookahead:

```
regexChecker("(?<=ieatrcxb)\\d{4,6}(?=-\\d)", line)
```

This returns just `4498`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = "150: 2017-06-14 18:02:21 INFO  monitorinfo           :     Info: Lock VCS on node \"ieatrcxb4498-1\"";
    String regex ="ieatrcxb.*1";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

or if the id's are all quoted:

```
 String id = line.substring(line.indexOf("\""), line.lastIndexOf("\"")+1);
 System.out.println(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do it by very difficult way. If each line of the `lock-unlock.txt` file is the same like on snippet you posted, you can do following:

```
File logFile = new File("lock-unlock.txt");

List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(logFile.toPath());

List<Integer> ids = lines.stream()
                .filter(line -> line.contains("ieatrcxb"))
                .map(line -> line.split( "\"")[1]) //"ieatrcxb4498-1"
                .map(line -> line.replaceAll("\\D+","")) //"44981"
                .map(Integer::parseInt) // 44981
                .collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

If you are not looking for just the ID number, just remove/comment second and third `.map()` method call, but it will result to a List of Strings instead of Integers.